# css positioning in One column fixed width layout

Tags: css

I have the css layout: One column fixed width layout, from [maxdesign.com](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/)

the following is the navigation div:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDataEntry" runat="server">Data Entry</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbReports" runat="server">Reports</asp:LinkButton></li>                
        </ul>           
    </div>
```

Now, I want to place an asp:label with the current user logged in, in the same navigation div by doing this:

```
 <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDataEntry" runat="server">Data Entry</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbReports" runat="server">Reports</asp:LinkButton></li>                
        </ul>  
        <div id="username">
            <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="User name"></asp:Label>
        </div>         
    </div>
```

with the css code:

```
    #navigation
{
    float: left;
    width: 960px;
    background: #1f2d3a;    
}

#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    color:#fff; 
    font-size: 14px;
    /*font-weight: bold;*/  
    border-right: 1px solid#fff;
}

#navigation li a:hover { background:#0c749b; }

    #username
{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

But the label is always shown below the line of menu items, at the right but below them.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not place the label in a right floated `li`, inside `#navigation`? Your CSS can stay the same, since `#username` is floated right already.

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDataEntry" runat="server">Data Entry</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbReports" runat="server">Reports</asp:LinkButton></li>                
            <li id="username"><asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="User name"></asp:Label></li>
        </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! that's what I did, and it worked (9 min to accept your answer) :)

Comment: Happy to help! :) `Float` property is one of the most daunting things to learn in CSS

Answer (score 1):

you need to float the ul. right now the ul is a block element, meaning anything after it will show up on the next line, thus the username is below it.  if you assign a float:left, it should allow elements to appear in the empty space to the right of the list.